# CoreOS: Is it possible to start an unit with cloud-init, which is manageable by fleet?

Tags: coreos, cloud-init

Can I start units with cloud-init, so that they are manageable by fleet afterwards?

It seems, that only normal systemd services can be started by cloud-unit, but without having them under fleet control. Is this right?

What would be a possible solution to automatically start specific services after the cluster is bootstrapped?

**SOLVED:**

```
#cloud-config

write_files:
  - path: /home/core/foo.service
    owner: core:core
    permissions: 0644
    content: |
        [Unit]
        Description=Foo
        Requires=docker.service
        After=docker.service

        [Service]
        User=core
        TimeoutStartSec=0
        KillMode=none
        EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
        ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill foo
        ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm foo
        ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull registry.example.com/foo
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name foo registry.example.com/foo
        ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop foo

coreos:
  etcd:
    discovery: https://discovery.etcd.io/<token>
    addr: $private_ipv4:4001
    peer-addr: $private_ipv4:7001
  units:
    - name: etcd.service
      command: start
    - name: fleet.service
      command: start
    - name: auto-start-foo.service
      command: start
      content: |     
        [Unit]
        Description=Autostarts foo-service
        Requires=docker.service
        After=docker.service

        [Service]
        WorkingDirectory=/home/core/
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/fleetctl start foo.service
        Type=oneshot
```

Answer (score 0):

A few weeks ago I was wondering the same thing.  The approach presented by the OP used fleetctl to launch the process.  I think that had the affect of being able to do fleetctl list-units and the launched process would be listed and managed by fleet.

You could put the content from the write_files down in the units: section and get rid of the write_files section, like this:

```
#cloud-config

coreos:
  etcd:
    discovery: https://discovery.etcd.io/<token>
    addr: $private_ipv4:4001
    peer-addr: $private_ipv4:7001
  units:
    - name: etcd.service
      command: start
    - name: fleet.service
      command: start
    - name: foo.service
      command: start
      content: |
        [Unit]
        Description=Foo
        Requires=docker.service
        After=docker.service

        [Service]
        User=core
        TimeoutStartSec=0
        KillMode=none
        EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
        ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill foo
        ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm foo
        ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull registry.example.com/foo
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name foo registry.example.com/foo
        ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop foo
```

but, that does mean that:

- you won't see the unit when you do a fleetctl list-units, it is being
  managed by the underlying systemd.
- if the unit fails because this host fails it won't migrate to another
  fleet host.

Thank you for the great question and answer @mbo :-)

Comment: Yes, that was my first attempt. But I needed the unit manageable by fleetctl, so the way over write_files was mandatory for me.

Comment: yes, makes sense.  i guess you only send the foo.service to one or two of your fleet hosts, right?   if you are sending the service to all of them then it would make sense to not use the fleetctl launch technique and simply put it in the units stanza.  I think the big difference is in your solution, fleet manages the unit (very possibly putting it on a different host). In the solution where you put it in units stanza, that unit runs on that machine. it is still managed (by systemd). you can see it with systemctl status foo.service.

Comment: I do indeed send the service to all hosts, but fleet manages to get it right and only starts one unit, as wanted.

I want this unit to be managed by fleet, cause I want to be able to upgrade it or manage it otherwise through fleet.